# Unable to enable modules Cannot enable Magento_Paypal because it depends on disabled modules:

Tags: magento2, installation

I am getting this error while installing Magento 2.3.0.

> Unable to enable modules because of the following constraints: Cannot
>   enable Magento_Paypal because it depends on disabled modules: Unable
>   to enable modules because of the following constraints: Cannot enable
>   Magento_Braintree because it depends on disabled modules:
>   Magento_InstantPurchase: Magento_Braintree->Magento_InstantPurchase
>
> Magento_InstantPurchase: Magento_Paypal->Magento_InstantPurchase
>   Cannot enable Magento_Sitemap because it depends on disabled modules:
>   Magento_Robots: Magento_Sitemap->Magento_Robots

I googled for this error but nothing helpful found.Please help me to fix this error. Or let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: switch from Mozzila to Chrome

Comment: are you updating ?

Comment: I am installing new

Comment: I am using chrome incognito mode.

Comment: Will it create problem in future use?

Comment: Yes I have solved in firefox. Will this error create problem in future magento use

Comment: Giving error again but i have all modules enabled

Comment: what will happen if i will unselect all the optional modules in installation

Answer (score 1):

Look at error, you need to enable next modules :

1. Magento_Braintree
2. Magento_InstantPurchase
3. Magento_Sitemap
4. Magento_Robots

just enable them and everything will be good. 
Paypal module wont work without this modules.

```
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Braintree
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_InstantPurchase
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Sitemap
php bin/magento module:enable Magento_Robots



php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: Can I forecfully enable these modules

Comment: yes, look at my edits in answer

Comment: Now I am getting this error:

Comment: [ERROR] Magento\Framework\Setup\Exception: Unable to apply patch Magento\InventorySales\Setup\Patch\Schema\InitializeWebsiteDefaultSock for module Magento_InventorySales. Original exception message: The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again. in /var/www/m2.gocleaning.nl/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Patch/PatchApplier.php:232

Comment: All modules are enabled but still getting error

Comment: add to answer one more

Comment: i think it is in database table sale channels, you need change code for yours website code

Comment: I am installing a fresh magento but getting this error

Comment: what will happen if i will unselect all the optional modules in installation.

Comment: paypal - wont work